# No Results - UITableView iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to display a no results message on my tableview when it is empty. I have done the uilabel approach where it appears when it is empty but it seems like it's not how Apple has done it in the Contacts etc where the "No Results" move as well when you try to scroll up and down. Mine just stays there in one spot.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I think they added a No Results cell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. If you have no results to display, do the following

1. Create a boolean flag named *noResultsToDisplay*, or something else.
2. If you have no results to display then set `noResultsToDisplay = YES`, set it to `NO` otherwise.
3. In *numberOfRowsInSection*, `if (noResultsToDisplay) return 3;`
4. In *cellForRowAtIndexPath*, `if (noResultsToDisplay && indexPath.row == 2) cell.textLabel.text = @"No Results";`

Comment: would I put 2. in the viewDidLoad? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Simon, when I put 2. into _cellForRowAtIndexPath_, I will get 2 errors of undeclared identifier for _noResultsToDisplay_ and _numberOfRowsInSection_. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: @K.Honda, Sorry again. You have to create a BOOL variable named *noResultsToDisplay*. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: @Simon, I have done the above but it seems like it's not showing up. I set breakpoints on the above and it's not getting them either :/

Comment: It seems like it's going through `if (noResultsToDisplay) return 3;`. So it's not returning 3...

Comment: @K.Honda, Are you setting *noResultsToDisplay* properly? Can you post your code, if possible.

Comment: This approach should be ok when you have simple cell.  Otherwise, this require special handling all over the place to handle action such as selection, deletion, etc.  Using table header may  be a better option.

Answer (score 3):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty cell";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two way of doing it: Either do as you suggest yourself, make a "No Results Cell" and have a state in your tableViewController that is BOOL resultIsEmpty = YES. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath you first test for this empty BOOL and return only the no result cell , remember to also check in numberOfRowsInSection so you can return 1 in the case of empty (otherwise it will probably return the length of your model array which of course is 0).

The other way is to make a y inset on the table view and place your label there. This can be done because UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(heighOfNoResultLabel, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then in the "resultsDidLoad" or what your delegate for new data is called, you test if it is 0 and inset the tableView and place a label there. If it is not 0 set the inset to

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

all 0's. You can animate this property, so that when there are no results, the tableview "scrolls" down to reveal the the "No Results" Label.

Bot solutions are valid I would say, about the same amount of code. The difference is probably what you can do with it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by maintaining a label view with the same farme as the table has, and play with the "hidden" attribute of the label and table (always one is YES and the other is NO).

Answer (score 0):

```
i have edited the accepted answer to be look like the no search results in tableView


    Create a boolean flag named noResultsToDisplay, or something else.
    1-If you have no results to display then set noResultsToDisplay = YES, set it to NO otherwise.
    2-(this step changed)In numberOfRowsInSection, if (noResultsToDisplay) return 1; 
// 1 returned not 3

   3-(this step changed) In cellForRowAtIndexPath, 

static NSString *CellIdentifier;
    if (noResultsToDisplay){
        CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
// in my case i use custom cell this step can be skipped if you use the default UITableViewCell
    }
    else{
       CellIdentifier = @"DocInqueryCell";
    }
 DocumentationInqueryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// don't forgt to add cell in your storyboard with identifier Cell and class your custom class , again this step can be skipped if you use the default cell

then 
if (noResultsToDisplay) {
cell.textLabel.text = @"No Results";
}else{

do what you want in your custom cell

}
```